# Updating AutoMapper to version 5.0 makes ITypeConverter and Profiles conflicting

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've ported the following profiles from Automapper 4.2.1 to 5.0, moving what I had in the now obsolete `Configure()` method in the constructor of profiles, and changing the signature of the `Convert` method in the expressions.

```
public class AuthorModelToDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public AuthorModelToDtoProfile() {
        CreateMap<Author, AuthorDto>()
            .ForMember(a => a.AuthorId, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
            .ForMember(a => a.FullName, o => o.MapFrom(m => $"{m.FirstName} {m.Surname}"));
    }
}

public class BookModelToDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public BookModelToDtoProfile() {
        CreateMap<IEnumerable<Genre>, IEnumerable<int>>()
            .ConvertUsing(new GenreExpression());
    }
}

public class GenreExpression : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<Genre>, IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Convert(IEnumerable<Genre> source, ResolutionContext context)
        => source.Select(g => g.Id);
}
```

Now, after these changes, the following configuration throws an `ArgumentException`, saying it can't use an expression of type string for a parameter of type `IEnumerable<Genre>`:

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.AddProfile<BookModelToDtoProfile>();
    c.AddProfile<AuthorModelToDtoProfile>();
    c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
});
```

Strangely, if I comment one or the other of the profile additions, the creation of the mapper configuration doesn't throw anymore any exception and it maps correctly from `Author` to `AuthorDto` or from `Book` to `BookDto`, based on what I commented, which makes me think that every profile on its own is correct.

I can avoid using the `TypeConverter` in the presented situation, but I have more complex expressions where the `.ConvertUsing(...)` helps readability and maintainability of my code.

Anyone had the same problem or is able to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been fixed on version 5.0.2.